# unable to find content_transformer in tm

Tags: r, data-mining, tm, text-analysis

Is content_transformer function removed from tm package 0.6-2 ??

```
library(tm)
docs<-Corpus(DirSource("Dname"))
docs<-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(gsub), pattern="using",replacement="use")
Error: could not find function "content_transformer"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to update the package. [This GitHub repository](https://github.com/cran/tm/blob/master/NAMESPACE#L12) shows that the function is exported and is also [present in the code](https://github.com/cran/tm/blob/b48a92d72b71ce43eabad5ee43708afb86e3bfb8/R/transform.R#L59).

```
> library(tm)
Loading required package: NLP
> content_transformer
function (FUN) 
function(x, ...) {
    content(x) <- FUN(content(x), ...)
    x
}
<environment: namespace:tm>

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                        LC_TIME=Slovenian_Slovenia.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tm_0.6-2  NLP_0.1-9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] rsconnect_0.4.1.4 parallel_3.2.3    tools_3.2.3       slam_0.1-35
```